# Acrobat reader 64 bit for 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04

Does anybody know where can I get Adobe Acrobat for 64 bit Ubuntu? I see the question was asked 4 years ago,there was activity 2 years ago. Has any movement been made to get a 64 bit reader?

I looked at the web site for Acrobat but didn't see anything but a 32 bit download. I wanted to check before we changed our 64 bit script to use the 32 bit. The example is what we use, thanks.

Comment: Did you ask  Adobe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe never made a 64-bit Acrobat Reader for Linux.

For some time they built a 32-bit version of it, but stopped at 9.5.5.

New versions of Acrobat reader are not available for Linux.

Older versions can be found, but they have serious security issues.

As for "Has any movement been made to get a 64 bit reader?".

Yes, it has been made. They stopped supporting Linux at all.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was coming up with just wanted to kick it out there.

Answer (score 0):

**Acrobat reader** is a **Adobe Product** and you can download adobe reader from the link

[Adobe Acrobat Reader Download](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb)  **Linux installer is no longer available.**

*Please select the OS and version from the url* : [Here](https://get.adobe.com/reader/otherversions/)

*Refer the hardware OS requirements*: [Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/reader/system-requirements.html)

Comment: There is no need to give a deb file execution permissions. And this is a 32-bit obsolete reader with security issues.

Comment: Ok I have updated answer Thanks! @ Pilot6